# Windows-1251 в QVector<quint8>

Tags: c++, qt

На вход поступает `QString` кодировки **Windows-1251**. Мне необходимо записать её в `QVector<quint8>` с возможностью дальнейшего извлечения под кодеком **СР866**.

Такой вариант не помог.

```
QByteArray msg;
msg.append(strInWindows1251);
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("Windows-1251");
QString res = codec->toUnicode(msg);
```

Более того, размер строки увеличивается (было 8 стало 15). Замена Windows-1251 на CP866 тоже не помогла

Кракозябра появляется лишь при наличии кириллицы.

Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось намного проще.

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("CP866");
QByteArray baStr = codec->fromUnicode(strNewData);
```

Answer (score 1):

QString::toLocal8bit вернет вам qbytearray

Comment: можете подсказать как бороться в изменённым размером QByteArray? например, если строка состояла из 8 символов, то размер QbyteArray становится 15

Comment: может у вас русские символы которые при попадании в  QString конвертируются в utf-8 и занимают больше одного байта.